# I'm looking for a word that defines a situation commonly used in TV/film writing

Tags: meaning

Is there a definition, or a set of categories that describe situations in tv shows, movies, etc.

Example,

When the protagonist is a social underdog and his love interest is that of the "unreachable popular girl" persona who is dating the jock- the antagonist. 
It seems to happen in many scenes throughout many movies, that *the protagonist interacts with the antagonist in a way that shows the protagonist is in fact, suave, down-to-earth, and funny - while the antagonist becomes embarrassed, or looks like a fool in front of his girlfriend.*

Comment: The protagonist is shown in a good light while the jock antagonist looks bad in front of the girl? I think the technical term for that is "wishful thinking".

Answer (score 4):

It could be a "**cliché**", or perhaps the word you're after is "**trope**"...

> **Tropes** are devices and conventions that a writer can reasonably rely on as being present in the audience members' minds and expectations.

[TV Tropes.com](http://tvtropes.org/) has a large index of common tropes used in TV, film, literature and other areas...